# Regex to find only colon in "asdf:adsf" but not "asdf: adsf"

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to use regex to capture ONLY the colon in something like `asdf:adsf`, which could also look like `a:b`, `asdf:b`, `b:asdf`,`123:b`,`2:1`, etc. However, it SHOULD NOT match `asdf: adsf`, `a: b`, `asdf :b`, `b: asdf`, `123 : b`, `2: 1`,

So far I have tried a slew of different regexes, and the closest I've come is:

```
\x20*:\x20* // wrong because this captures all whitespace
```

Comment: I don't understand, why not `/(:)/`?

Comment: @thomas it's too broad for what I'm doing...it would match in a lot of other instances than just "asdf:asdf" see https://www.regex101.com/r/bG7fW6/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\S(:)(?=\S)
```

Try this.Grab the capture or group.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/fA6wE2/29

```
var re = /\S(:)(?=\S)/gm;
var str = 'a:b\nasas:b\na:sadasd\na: sdffds\na :asfsd\na : dsfdf';
var m;

while ((m = re.exec(str)) != null) {
if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
re.lastIndex++;
}
// View your result using the m-variable.
// eg m[0] etc.
}
```

Comment: I apologize @vks but I didn't realize that javascript regex is different from php regex...this is for JS so I'm getting an error.

Comment: @maudulus you have to grab the capture or group.

Comment: No, it is matching them but not grabbing them. See the grabbed matches in the dialog on the right with "match 1", "match 2", "match 3".

Answer (score 1):

```
\w+(?=\S):(?=\S)\w+
```

This will solve the problem.

My other answer was deleted with that regex posted before.